# No overloads for "pd.read_csv()" match parameters Argument types: (Literal['../cleaned_data.csv.zip'], Literal['zip'])

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pylance

How to fix the following warning from VS Code:

```
No overloads for "pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=input_dir, compression='zip')" match parameters
  Argument types: (Literal['../cleaned_data.csv.zip'], Literal['zip'])Pylance (reportGeneralTypeIssues)
```

for the code

```
cleaned_df = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer = input_dir, compression = 'zip')
```

P.S. This error is from [Pylance](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/announcing-pylance-fast-feature-rich-language-support-for-python-in-visual-studio-code/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Workaround

Pass `filepath_or_buffer` as a positional argument and not as a keyword argument:

```
cleaned_df = pd.read_csv(input_dir, compression = 'zip')
```

## Explication

Pandas [code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/5011a371a54f1dcf5a01d6e23b2331aab405667e/pandas/io/parsers.py#L536) and [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) say that the first argument is named `filepath_or_buffer` but the module stub used for typing says it is named `filepath`.

Pandas code:

[image]

Pylance stub:

[image]

If you prefer ignoring the error and wait for a future fix from Pylance you can do the following:

```
cleaned_df = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer = "aaa", compression = 'zip') # type: ignore
```

Of course ignoring type errors is not good practice but this is a bug in the type checker so..